# Are background workers stopped when process that created them finishes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a `Windows Service` that when it gets started It creates many **backgroundworkers**. and each backgroundworker monitors its own Queue in memory with the pending items to process.

**When the process that created the backgroundworkers** --windows service-- **is stopped** (either by request or because it crashed) **are these background workers stoped or left orphan and still running ?**

**Do I need to write the code stop the backgropund workers when the windows service is about to be stopped ?**

Comment: They stop when *all* non-background threads complete.

Comment: This is something you can test yourself with a short application.

Comment: @Gusdor I already have an application I am looking for an answer based on concepts/trusted sources and learn this way not by trial an error which is my usual approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker`s use threads with [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) set to true, which means it will terminate when all non-background threads have terminated.

If your BackgroundWorker is going to do something where it should not be shut-down until it is completed, then it should set `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false` before it begins that crucial part, and set it back to `true` upon completion.

Edit: It's worth adding, that a process shutdown (unhandled exception, process killed through the task-manager or replacement, etc.) will end **all** threads. It's rather the reverse; ending all non-background threads will end the process (and take all background threads with them). It's this you need to worry about in terms of reacting to user input requesting the process terminate (service stop, last visible window closed, etc.)

Comment: @ JonHanna What I need is to know if Do I need to write the code stop the backgropund workers when the windows service is stopped

Comment: @MauricioGracia I would say that it depends on what your treads are doing but on the whole to ensure that what ever they are doing stops gracefully, any data is saved, any communications are concluded etc. Otherwise if the worker doesn't support cancellation the thread might terminate in the middle of doing something important.

Comment: No, you only need to worry about it if they start doing something where shutdown would be a problem, the default is that they'll end when all non-background threads end.

Comment: @Ashigore I already have a mechanism to recover the job once the windows service is stopped and started so I need to make sure that they background workers get stopped and disposed to avoid memory leaks or leaving thread that consume memory

Comment: @MauricioGracia If you are not concerned with the theads terminating in the middle of something then you need not worry about disposing of them. They will not linger after the non-background threads terminate.

Comment: Is it possible to use finally blocks or otherwise cleanly shut down? [Background threads are not terminated with a `ThreadAbortException`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET applications and services when the main thread terminates all <strike>child</strike> background threads terminate as well.

Comment: Not true. A thread with its IsBackground property set to true will tmerinate alongside the main thread. Otherwise, the app will not terminate until all other threads are finished.

Comment: What does "main thread" even mean. If you've got two non-background threads, who died to make one "main"?

Comment: I "know perfectly well" no such thing.

Comment: OK so what would you call it? "The Thread Which the Application Initially Runs Under Thread"? We might need a shorter way to express that...

Comment: @JonHanna I have improve the question so that is clear that what I mean by "main thread" is the process that created the backgrounworkers

Comment: @MauricioGracia it's a good distinction. There's no reason why a service need not have more than one non-background thread running at a given point in time, and then they'd be on an equal footing as far as the process continuing goes.